# Not able to input text in html text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, drag

I have a script that makes me able to drag some content in a div.

But because you can drag around, no matter where you place the cursor in the div, I am not able to input some text in a text field.

Is it possible to allow that?

I can eaily click links in the div container. But not input text in a html input field.

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#roadmap').mousedown(function (event) {
    $(this)
    .data('down', true)
    .data('x', event.clientX)
    .data('scrollLeft', this.scrollLeft);

    return false;
}).mouseup(function (event) {
    $(this).data('down', false);
}).mousemove(function (event) {
    if ($(this).data('down') == true) {
        this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollLeft') + $(this).data('x') - event.clientX;
    }
}).mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
}).css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'cursor': 'col-resize'
});
});
$(window).mouseout(function (event) {
    if ($('#roadmap').data('down')) {
        try {
            if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'BODY' || event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'HTML') {
                $('#roadmap').data('down', false);
            }
        } catch (e) { }
    }
});
```

This is my extended mousewheel function (if needed)

```
(function ($) {

    $.event.special.mousewheel = {
        setup: function () {
            var handler = $.event.special.mousewheel.handler;

            // Fix pageX, pageY, clientX and clientY for mozilla
            if ($.browser.mozilla)
                $(this).bind('mousemove.mousewheel', function (event) {
                    $.data(this, 'mwcursorposdata', {
                        pageX: event.pageX,
                        pageY: event.pageY,
                        clientX: event.clientX,
                        clientY: event.clientY
                    });
                });

            if (this.addEventListener)
                this.addEventListener(($.browser.mozilla ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel'), handler, false);
            else
                this.onmousewheel = handler;
        },

        teardown: function () {
            var handler = $.event.special.mousewheel.handler;

            $(this).unbind('mousemove.mousewheel');

            if (this.removeEventListener)
                this.removeEventListener(($.browser.mozilla ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel'), handler, false);
            else
                this.onmousewheel = function () { };

            $.removeData(this, 'mwcursorposdata');
        },

        handler: function (event) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

            event = $.event.fix(event || window.event);
            // Get correct pageX, pageY, clientX and clientY for mozilla
            $.extend(event, $.data(this, 'mwcursorposdata') || {});
            var delta = 0, returnValue = true;

            if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
            if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;
            if ($.browser.opera) delta = -event.wheelDelta;

            event.data = event.data || {};
            event.type = "mousewheel";

            // Add delta to the front of the arguments
            args.unshift(delta);
            // Add event to the front of the arguments
            args.unshift(event);

            return $.event.handle.apply(this, args);
        }
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        mousewheel: function (fn) {
            return fn ? this.bind("mousewheel", fn) : this.trigger("mousewheel");
        },

        unmousewheel: function (fn) {
            return this.unbind("mousewheel", fn);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

And here goes the HTML

```
<div id="roadmap">
       <ul>
           <li class="roadmap_description">
             <h2>Welcome</h2>
             <p>Description</p>
           </li>
           <li><h3 class="milestone_name">v. 1.0.2.3</h3>
               <ul>
                    <li class="milestone_item"><a href="#">Title description</a></li>
               </ul>
                <div class="milestone_item_add">
                     <input class="field" name="milestone_item_name" type="text" /><a href="#"><img src="/Intranet/admin/Intranet/css/images/icons/wand.png" alt="Add new" /></a>
                </div>
           </li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It'd probably be good to see the HTML too. If you can't type into the field, it may be because some element is on top of it, thus blocking events. An element that's covered up by another element - even if it's still visible - cannot get focus. (Though you might see if you can tab to it ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return false` in `mousedown` prevents the mouse button press from having its default action, which is to focus the child `<input>`.

You could test `event.target` in the `mousedown` function to see if it's the `<input>` element, and if so just stop trying to handle it (`return` or `return true` straight away).

If you wanted to still allow the element to be dragged when the mouse is in the `<input>`, you could still `return false` but manually call `focus()` on the input in `mousedown`. The disadvantage of that would be that the user couldn't use drags to select part of the text, as inputs would normally allow.

Comment: Nice, this works! :-) I used: if (event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') { return true; } But is it possible to check up against a $(".class")?

Comment: Sure, you might do eg. `if ($(event.target).hasClass('someclass'))`. (Incidentally, when checking `tagName`/`nodeName` on an HTML document you should use eg. `.toLowerCase()` to test it case-insensitively. Alternatively, in jQuery style, check against a selector, avoiding the problem: `if ($(event.target).is('input'))`.)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add a mouseover event to the textfield that sets this: $(this).data('down', false); ?